# Tensorflow.js: Error in gradient for op maximum. The gradient of input '$a' has shape '32,200', which does not match the shape of the input '32,1'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I built a very simple Tensorflow operation, and everything seems to make sense, but when I call the `fit` function, the model fails to backpropagate the gradients with the above error message:

```
Error in gradient for op maximum. 

The gradient of input '$a' has shape '32,200', 
which does not match the shape of the input '32,1'
```

Here are the types of `xTrain` and `yTrain`

```
xTrain
  Array(3) [2000, 20, 73]
  float32
yTrain
  Array(2) [2000, 200]
  float32
```

Here are the expected input and output of the model:

```
model.input
  Array(3) [null, 20, 73]
  float32
model.outputs[0]
  Array(2) [null, 200]
  float32
```

[EDIT] I should note that my problem only happen when I try to use

```
loss: 'cosineProximity'
```

Here is my code:

```js
console.log("starting compute_and_save_model");

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.simpleRNN({
    units: length_of_embedding,//amount_of_rnn_units,
    recurrentInitializer: 'glorotNormal',
    inputShape: [max_len, recogized_letters.length],
    return_sequences: false,
}));

console.log(model.input.shape);
console.log(model.input.dtype);
console.log(model.outputs[0].shape);
console.log(model.outputs[0].dtype);
console.log(model.batchInputShape);

model.compile({
    loss: 'cosineProximity',
    optimizer: 'adam',
    metrics: ['acc']
});

console.log("starting compute_and_save_model (fit)")

await model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, {
    epochs: 2,
    batchSize: 32,
    validationSplit: 0.2,
    callbacks: {
        onBatchBegin(b) {
            console.log("starting compute_and_save_model (fit:"+b+")");
        }
    }
});
```

> Runnable from https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ddlwge

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here?

> EDIT: I tried to create my own `cosineProximity` implementation and get the same error. For reference here was my implementation of the `cosineProximity`:
>
> ```js
> const cosine = tf.layers.dot({axes: -1,normalize:true})
> ```
>
> ```js
> loss: function(a,b) {
>     return tf.neg(tf.mean(cosine.apply([a,b])));
> },
> ```

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the main issue, but I managed to get the model running just by replacing the 'cosineSimilarity' loss by a 'meanSquaredError' loss. I'm still interested in understanding why the cosineSimilarity loss isn't working, and what I need to do to make it work.

Comment: Can you add more code about your model and your label and features shape ?

Comment: @edkeveked Sure, what do you wish you had in addition to what is there? As far as I know there is nothing more to it than the code I pasted and the tensors xTrain and yTrain which I already described above in the text.

Comment: Could you do a snippet using stackblitz.com that can throw the same error ?

Comment: @edkeveked https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ddlwge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I spent some time on this, and it looks like this is an error in the Tensforflow.js implementation.

If you are facing the same issue, you can fix it by applying the following patch yourself (I'm sure tfjs-layers maintainers will merge this pull request eventually, so hopefully you won't have this problem again in the future).

> https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/pull/499

```
| export function l2Normalize(x: Tensor, axis?: number): Tensor {
|   return tidy(() => {
|     const squareSum = tfc.sum(K.square(x), axis, true);
-     const epsilonTensor = tfc.mul(scalar(epsilon()), tfc.onesLike(x));
+     const epsilonTensor = tfc.mul(scalar(epsilon()), tfc.onesLike(squareSum));
|     const norm = tfc.sqrt(tfc.maximum(squareSum, epsilonTensor));
|     return tfc.div(x, norm);
|   });
| }
```

Comment: The pull request has now been merged.